# Which of the following formulas hold for all invertible $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Which of the following formulas hold for all invertible $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$?

1. $(AB)^{-1} = A^{-1}B^{-1}$
2. $ABA^{-1} = B$
3. $(A + B)(A - B) = A^2 - B^2$
4. $A^7$ is invertible
5. $(I_n + A)(I_n + A^{-1}) = 2I_n + A + A^{-1}$
6. $A + I_n$ is invertible

I have learned the basic rules of matrices but the formulas above seem far more complex that what I have learned. Any help, please?

Comment: @BangPhamKhoa Just $D$ and $E$ are true. $B$ does not hold in general.

Comment: This is clearly an exercise. What have you tried to do so far? Please provide some details about all of the 6 points.

Comment: Where does this come from?

Answer (score 0):

$(AB)^{-1}AB=I$ so $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1} $.

the second is wrong. so the third must be of the following form
$$(A + B)(A - B) = A^2 - B^2-AB+BA.$$

We know that a square matrix is invertible iff $\det A\neq 0$ and by determinant properties we have  $\det A^7=(\det A)^7$. By setting $A=-I_n$ then $A + I_n$ is not invertible.